# Flatness of localizations

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization, flatness, local-rings

Let $R \subseteq A$ be two $\mathbb{C}$-algebras, $P$ a prime ideal of $R$, $Q$ a prime ideal of $A$, and $Q \cap R = P$. Assume that $(A_Q,QA_Q)$ is flat over $(R_P,PR_P)$.

> 'When' $A$ is flat over $R$?

I do not mind to further assume that the above local rings are regular;
by [Auslander-Buchsbaum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auslander%E2%80%93Buchsbaum_theorem) theorem, such rings are UFD's.

Perhaps [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2803986/localization-and-flatness) question may help.

**Remark:** I have edited the original question, according to the comments below.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I expect this is not true. Flatness of the ring morphism $R \to A$ should be a (stalk) local property, in the sense that for any $P \in Spec(R)$ and any $Q$ in $Spec(A)$ whose contraction to $R$ is $P$, the associated map $R_{P} \to A_{Q}$ must be flat. Here, you've only required it for one possible pair $(P, Q)$, and it's not even necessarily the case that $Q$ contracts to $P$. To be explicit, I expect something like the cuspidal cubic $R = \mathbb{C}[X, Y]/\langle Y^{2}-X^{3} \rangle$ and $A = \mathbb{C}[X]$ should give a counterexample.

Comment: To wit, I'm pretty sure that the natural map $R \to A$ is etale (hence flat) away from the ''origin'' (i.e. away from the prime ideal $\langle X, Y \rangle$ of $R$), and so picking any other point of $Spec(R)$ should do.

Comment: Thank you. Truly I had in mind a similar idea to yout first idea.  Your second  idea sounds interesting. Please, do you think that there exists an additional condition that would guarantee a positive answer to my question?

Comment: Nothing comes to mind for me. Like I said in my first comment, there's no getting around your ring morphism needing to be flat at each prime, so I don't know what conditions you'd put on $R$ and $A$ other than stupid ones (like each ring is local). Perhaps if $P$ and $Q$ are suitably chosen, then flatness for your particular choice of $P, Q$ implies flatness at every other prime - some kind of ''generic'' flatness argument. But I'm hardly an expert in such matters, and don't have anything specific in mind.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am curious if such a 'generic' flatness criterion exists.

Comment: Whoops. I'm realizing that my specific suggested example is not very good, because I think the natural map $R \to A$ is flat everywhere, and etale-ness fails for other reasons. But it still shouldn't be too hard to find an example which violates the same principle...

Comment: Thank you very much for the update! Please, if you have any ideas about the current question or the following question, you are welcome: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4084699/a-result-concerning-local-rings

Comment: What if R and A are integral domains and P=Q=(0)?

Comment: Very nice counterexample, thank you! Taking $R \subset A$ non-flat, the fields of fractions extension $Q(R) \subset Q(A)$ is flat, so this indeed answers my question in the negative. Do you think one can find 'special' $P$ and $Q$ that guarantee flatness of $R \subset A$. What about $P$ maximal in $R$, $Q$ maximal in $A$ (and $PA=Q$)? I guess there still exists a counterexample?

Comment: Your starting assumption should be $Q\cap R=P$; otherwise $A_Q$ is not naturally a module over $R_P$.  An extreme example is $A=R$, $P=0$, $Q\ne 0$.  In this case, $R_P$ is a field and $A_Q$ is a proper subset, and so $A_Q$ cannot be a vector space over $R_P$ in the natural way.

Comment: @AllenBell, thank you for your important comment.